# How to get a sound to stop playing in OpenAL

Tags: c++, openal

I am trying to have a play sound method execute on a click event, followed by a stop method being called on the release, using OpenAL in in C++. My problem is that I cannot get it to stop playing on the release. My source code to play the sound is as follows:

```
bool SoundManager::play(QString fileName, float pitch, float gain)
{
static uint sourceIndex = 0;
ALint state;

// Get the corresponding buffer id set up in the init function.
ALuint bufferID = mSoundBuffers[fileName];

if (bufferID != 0) {
    // Increment which source we are using, so that we play in a "free" source.
    sourceIndex = (sourceIndex + 1) % SOUNDMANAGER_MAX_NBR_OF_SOURCES;
    // Get the source in which the sound will be played.
    ALuint source = mSoundSources[sourceIndex];

    if (alIsSource (source) == AL_TRUE) {

        // Attach the buffer to an available source.
        alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);

        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
            reportOpenALError();
            return false;
        }

        // Set the source pitch value.
        alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, pitch);
        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
            reportOpenALError();
            return false;
        }

        // Set the source gain value.
        alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, gain);

        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
            reportOpenALError();
            return false;
        }
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
        if (state!=AL_PLAYING)
        alSourcePlay(source);
        else if(state==AL_PLAYING)
            alSourceStop(source);

        if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
            reportOpenALError();
            return false;
        }
    }
} else {
    // The buffer was not found.
    return false;
}`
```

I think that the issue is that when it is called the second time, when it should be stopped, it is a different source, and that is why its state is not playing. If this is the issue, then how can I access the same source?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's not the same source as before, you increase the `sourceIndex` variable each call.

So the first call, to play, `sourceIndex` will be `1` (`sourceIndex + 1`). The next time you call the function (which btw. is badly named for something that *toggles* playing) then `sourceIndex` again will be increased by one, which will give you a new index into the source vector.

Comment: Thanks yes, I tried an unchanging source as well as stopping all sources with alsourcestopv, but none seemed to work.